# jquery - get all td's in a table except those in the first two columns?

Tags: jquery

How do I retrieve the `td's` in a `tr` where the `td` index (within the row) is not 1 or 2? That is, I want to skip the first two columns. The following code gets the job done but is there a better way to do it? I'm thinking `(td eq(0) || eq(1))` something like that.

```
  $("#time-entry tr").each(function () {
            var trId = $(this).attr('id');
            $(String.format("#{0} td input[id^=txt]", trId)).each(function () { //rewrite
                var tdIndex = $(this).index();
                if(tdIndex != 1 && tdIndex != 2) {

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Just a note: don't forget that the index is passed into each(), such as $('td').each(function(index) { ... });

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of that. I think even the value gets passed. `$('td').each(function(index, value) { ... }); `

Comment: From one of your comments below: _"...I just need to loop row-by-row, grab all the textboxes..."_ - so why are worrying about selecting `td` elements? Just grab the textboxes (`input` elements?) directly. If you show some sample html from a row or two of your table you could get some suggestions about how to do that...

Comment: That's because the first two cells also have textboxes that I do not want. I apologize if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest an alternative approach, completely ignoring how to do things by index (which you can already see how to do from the other answers) and instead try to solve the underlying problem in a simple and maintainable way.

You said in a comment that what are really trying to do is add up some textboxes and put the row total in the last column, so to me it makes sense to select them directly rather than selecting the containing `td` elements. You did note that the first two columns have textboxes that you don't want to select but we can easily allow for that.

Rather than messing around with column indexes, which means you'll have to change your code if you later insert/delete/re-order columns, I suggest you give a common class to the elements you want to add up and then another class to the (last column) row-total elements. So something like this in your markup:

```
<tr>
   <td><input></td>
   <td><input></td>
   <td><input class="addup"></td>
   <td><input class="addup"></td>
   <td><input class="addup"></td>
   <td><input class="total"></td>
</tr>
```

(Obviously you'll have other attributes but that was just a sample to show the classes.)

Then the JS is really simple:

```
// process each row
$("tr").each(function() {
   var total = 0;
   // select all "addup" elements in the current row
   $(".addup", this).each(function() {
      // add to the row total, converting to a number with
      // the unary plus operator. TODO: add some validation to be
      // sure the user actually entered numeric data
      total += +this.value;
   });
   // display the total
   $(".total", this).val(total);
});
```

If you insert extra columns in the middle that shouldn't be added, no problem: without the "addup" class they'll be ignored automatically.

Note also that your code: `$(String.format("#{0} td input[id^=txt]", trId))` seems to be trying to use a C# method in the middle of your JavaScript, which won't work. But you don't need to worry about trying to select elements based on the current row's id because within the `$("tr").each()` handler the keyword `this` will refer to the current row so you can pass that to the `$()` function as context for the selection. So like `$(".addup", this)` as shown above.

Comment: This is a great solution! I keep forgetting that selecting the elements via css classes is much faster than doing the same via indexes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, `String.format` is a little js snippet I found on the web which works the same way as in C#.

Answer (score 6):

On the assumption that the 'index' is the index of that td in its parent tr

```
$("#time-entry tr td").not(":nth-child(1), :nth-child(2)");
```

**EDIT:- this one is shorter**

```
$("#time-entry td:not(:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))");
```

**EDIT 2:-**
About the index passed through the `.each()` function:
the selector *(e.g. $("td"))* will get you a list of elements the index it passes is the index it is in that list.

**EDIT 3:-** asking about `:gt()`

it looks for the index of the ***matched set***. So if the matched set is all the `<td>` elements in the table it won't work for you. It will work this way though:

```
$("#time-entry tr").each(function () {
    $("td:gt(1)", this).each(function(){
    });
});
```

But i don't know why one would favour this way over the other suggested ways.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't this one even shorter - `$('tr td:gt(1)')` ? Is there a performance hit?

Comment: @enigma performance wise? I haven't a clue. `gt(1)` will get all of the `<td>`s and skip the first two. `nth-child` will get the index of its parent. There is a difference ... which is why i started my post with "on the assumption ..." I'm not sure exactly what the question is saying. **Edited:- spelling/grammar and to be more presice in my wording**

Comment: FYI, I am the OP. Thank you for the explanation. I just need to loop row-by-row, grab all the textboxes, sum up all the numbers in them, and display the total in the last cell of the row. This is for a timesheet app.

Comment: I can see where the `nth-child` might be useful - get all td's where index is not `1, 2 or 7`. With `gt`, I cannot specify that.

Comment: @enigma Apologies for the first two version of my prev comment. You need to be more specific in your question. Did you want any `<td>` elements in columns after the first two? or you need all them except for the first two in the first row?

Comment: I want the tds that are not in the 1st or 2nd column for the first row, the same for second row and so on.

Comment: @engima then `:gt(1)` will work for you if you do an `.each(` on the row first and get the `<td>`s in that row. See my latest update

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr:gt(1) td')` should do it.

**Edit**: I misunderstood your original request and thought you wanted to select the cells in all but the first two rows. To get all cells in everything but the first column, try:

```
$('tr').each(function(){ 
    $('td:gt(1)',this).css('background','red')  
});
```

Which would color the background of all cells except those in the first two columns.

Comment: I want the `td's` that have index greater than 1, not the `tr`. Can I re-write your code like this - `$('tr td:gt(1)')` ? Edit: it works!

Comment: Ah sorry, the way I read your question it looked like you wanted the td for rows with an index greater than 1. But as you can see by your own test, my example works extended to the cells themselves.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the index in the callback as such:

```
$("#time-entry tr").each(function (index, value) {
  if (index != 1 || index != 2) 
  {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: This will skip the first two `<tr>`s. where as the OP is trying to skip `<td>`s

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fish.  note: nnnnnn's solution is the one that should be used.

```
$("#time-entry tr").each(function () {
    var tr = $(this),
        total = tr.find('td input:last'),
        entries = tr.find('td:gt(1):not(td:last)').find('input'),
        totalVal = 0;

    entries.each(function() { totalVal += parseInt($(this).val()); });
    total.val(totalVal);
});
```